# How do I access and use the variable in one python class in another class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two Python classes created with tkinter to start with. I have three variables storing different data in the first class, UserLogin. I want to be able access and use the values in two of those variable in another class, HomePage, that is also in the same file. The goal is that based on the user level, I want to display certain widgets. In other words, each user when logged in can only see certain number of widgets which is determined by his user level. The class HomePage is the window containing the widgets to be displayed, while the first class is the login widow. I have a shorter version of my code here. I'm having trouble posting all the codes, hence this shorter version.

```
import backend    
class UserLogin:
    def __init__(self, top):
        self.top = top
        '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
           top is the toplevel containing window.'''
        _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana2color = '#ececec' # Closest X11 color: 'gray92


    top.geometry("676x450+458+150")
    top.title("Some title here")
    top.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
    top.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
    top.configure(highlightcolor="black")

    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()

    def user_login():
        if len(username.get()) != 0 and len(password.get()) != 0:
            result = backend.log(username.get())
            if not result:
                self.messageBox.delete('1.0', END)
                self.messageBox.insert(END, 'Invalid Login')
            else:
                level = result[0]
                user_name = result[1]
                pass_word = result[2]
                if user_name == username.get() and pass_word == password.get():
                    new_window()
                else:
                    self.messageBox.delete('1.0', END)
                    self.messageBox.insert(END, 'Invalid Login')

        else:
            self.messageBox.delete('1.0', END)
            self.messageBox.insert(END, 'Username and Password required')

    # This function opens the window created in Class HomePage
    def new_window():
        self.newWindow = Toplevel(self.top)
        login = HomePage(self.newWindow)

class HomePage
class HomePage:
    def __init__(self, top):
        self.top = top
        '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
           top is the toplevel containing window.'''
        _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85' 
        _ana2color = '#ececec' # Closest X11 color: 'gray92' 
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        if sys.platform == "win32":
            self.style.theme_use('winnative')
        self.style.configure('.',background=_bgcolor)
        self.style.configure('.',foreground=_fgcolor)
        self.style.configure('.',font="TkDefaultFont")
        self.style.map('.',background=
            [('selected', _compcolor), ('active',_ana2color)])

    top.geometry("903x568+392+150")
    top.title("Some title here")
    top.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
    top.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
    top.configure(highlightcolor="black")

    self.linksFrame = Frame(top)
    self.linksFrame.place(relx=0.035, rely=0.052, relheight=0.875
                          , relwidth=0.272)
    self.linksFrame.configure(relief='groove')
    self.linksFrame.configure(borderwidth="2")
    self.linksFrame.configure(relief='groove')
    self.linksFrame.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
    self.linksFrame.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
    self.linksFrame.configure(highlightcolor="black")
    self.linksFrame.configure(width=235)

    # Then I want to be able to say here that:
    self.registerPat = Button(self.linksFrame)
    self.registerPat.place(relx=0.043, rely=0.079, height=34, width=217)
    self.registerPat.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
    self.registerPat.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
    self.registerPat.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
    self.registerPat.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
    self.registerPat.configure(foreground="#000000")
    self.registerPat.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
    self.registerPat.configure(highlightcolor="black")
    self.registerPat.configure(pady="0")
    self.registerPat.configure(relief='groove')
    self.registerPat.configure(text='''Register Patient''')
```

Comment: I guess you didn't go through my codes. From the UserLogin class, I have a function, user_login(), which is nested inside the __init__ method. It's inside that user_login() function that the variables I'm taking about are used. And for clarity, the values they store are not hard coded, but obtained from the username and password provided by the user on the username and password filed.

Comment: The third variable, level, is associated with each user, and is one of the values stored and retrieved from the database. If you look through my code well, you will see I imported a module, backend, which contains the implementation of connecting to and fetching the username, password, and level from the database. So look through my code well so that you have a clearer understanding of what is going on. Of course I understand how to access a method of another class by creating an instance of the class, but in this case, there is a difference

Comment: So based on each user level, I want to display some widgets in the HomePage. That's my objective

Answer (score 0):

The question is not so clear to me, I see you defining variables but hard-coding the values. Please try to fix the provided code for better understanding the code. 
One way to do what you want is by making `HomePage` class inherits from `UserLogin`, in this way you can get Userlogin's variables inside Homepage. Example:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Mart"
        self.age = 40
        self.height = 170

class Child(Parent):
    def show_info(self):
        print(self.name, self.age, self.height)
```

now if we defined `test = Child()` then `test.show_info()`, this will print the values defined in the Parent class.